# CSV to JSON conversion in Java

Tags: java, json, csv

Since I've looked far and wide for a good example of this to no avail, I have created my own using the `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` classes. It took me a while to realize that the `push` method for `JSONObject` overwrites everything previously pushed.

```
public static JSONArray getJSON(String url) throws IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        Object[] q = null;
        Deque<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();

        try{  
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            if (responseCode != 404){
                logger.info("Response" + response.getEntity().getContent());
                try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(
                               response.getEntity().getContent()))) {

                 if(reader != null){
                     String aux = "";
                     while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         queue.add(aux);
                     }
                     q = queue.toArray();

                     for(int i = 0; i < q.length; i++){

                         String[] row = q[i].toString().split(",");

                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                            json.put("col0", row[0]);
                            json.put("col1", row[1]);
                            json.put("col2", row[2]);
                            json.put("col3", row[3]);
                            json.put("col4", row[4]);
                            json.put("col5", row[5]);

                            jArray.put(json);


                     }
                 }
                }

             }
                }
                return null;

             }
             return jArray;
        }finally{
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The amazing [Jackson library supports CSV data format](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv) as well.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you provide some information about the libraries used in your code. For example, if I want to read about `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`, which json library do I need to search for?

The same observation goes for the java classes `HttpGet`, `HttpResponse`, `HttpClient` and `DefaultHttpClient`. Showing the imports of those classes would also be helpful.

Having said that I only have one suggestion to your code. It seems like you don't need to create the array of Objects from the queue of strings (`Object[] q = queue.toArray();`), you could just iterate over the elements in the queue and then process each element.

Instead of adding elements to the `jArray` object this way

```
        while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            queue.add(aux);
        }
        q = queue.toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
            String[] row = q[i].toString().split(",");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("col0", row[0]);
            json.put("col1", row[1]);
            json.put("col2", row[2]);
            json.put("col3", row[3]);
            json.put("col4", row[4]);
            json.put("col5", row[5]);
            jArray.put(json);
        }
```

I would add the elements in this other way

```
        while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            queue.add(aux);
        }

        for (String row : queue){
            String[] csvValues = row.toString().split(",");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("col0", csvValues[0]);
            json.put("col1", csvValues[1]);
            json.put("col2", csvValues[2]);
            json.put("col3", csvValues[3]);
            json.put("col4", csvValues[4]);
            json.put("col5", csvValues[5]);
            jArray.put(json);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try-with-resources

You should use try-with-resources when you have the opportunity if you HTTP library implements `AutoCloseable` for their connections. I think that `HttpGet` do implement the interface so it would be easier to not let connections leaked.

### Magic Number

> ```
>  if (responseCode != 404){
> ```

`404` is a known return code for HTTP and normally every good library will provide you with a classes that will have the constant for return code. Apache have `HttpStatus` with `SC_NOT_FOUND` representing `404`

### Methods

Don't hesitate to refine your code into smaller methods. This will help fleshed out individual part of the code and make it easier to read the code.

> ```
>                       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
>                       json.put("col0", row[0]);
>                       json.put("col1", row[1]);
>                       json.put("col2", row[2]);
>                       json.put("col3", row[3]);
>                       json.put("col4", row[4]);
>                       json.put("col5", row[5]);
> ```

This would have been a perfect candidate to be a method `createJsonObject` which return the created object. You could have use a loop here too since you're repeating the same line 5 times (maybe more or less later if your format change)

### Formatting

Your code is in a weird format, I don't know if you had a hard time with the format in the question or if your code is like this, but note that you're not following a standard that I know. Using a common standard will go a long way to help the readability of your code.